# CakePHP 3 include custom lib

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.x I had static classes inside:

```
\app\Lib\Util\MyStaticClass1.php
\app\Lib\Util\MyStaticClass2.php
```

Then in `app\Config\bootstrap.php` file I added these lines.

```
App::uses('MyStaticClass1', 'Lib/Util');
App::uses('MyStaticClass2', 'Lib/Util');
```

So I didn't include these classes in every controller, component, helper or ctp file.

How can I do this in CakePHP 3 ? I tried this:

I copied these files to

`\src\Util\MyStaticClass1.php`
`\src\Util\MyStaticClass2.php`

Then inside every controller, component, helper and ctp file I added this:

```
use App\Util\MyStaticClass1;
use App\Util\MyStaticClass2;
```

This works. But is there an easier way to include these files ?

Comment: [This related question has an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31357351/722036)

Answer (score 0):

> But is there an easier way to include these files ?

I don't think so that's how the namespaces work. You could wrap the static method class in traits. See the EventManagerTrait of the core for example.

> I had static classes (...)  inside every controller, component, helper

This is **bad** practice and introduces tight coupling. I think your application architecture needs a serious overhaul if you used them everywhere extensively.

Comment: I generally use these static classes for string manipulations. I have components, helpers etc for controllers and views. But I need some utility functions to use. So I created Lib/Util files in cakephp 2.