# Cakephp 3 loading vendor files

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, vendor

In cakephp 2 when I need a vendor or related class to be loaded globally, i was adding require or app use inside bootstrap.php ot core php.

In cakephp 3 where should I require vendor files ? I dont want to declare vendor require in every class and template file that I use my vendor files.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files

Comment: Are your vendor files being installed with Composer?

Comment: No. I have my custom static utility classes. And I want to use them in my application. In cakephp 2 I was using Lib/Util folder for this operation. But it seems like in Cakephp 3 I should put them into vendor folder and load them. These vendor files doesn't belong to a online repo. I dont want to share its code publicly. So I store and develop them locally. I would prefer and similar method that works like old Lib/Util style.

Comment: What did you not find in the link you provided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vendor files are 3rdparty files. You custom static utility classes are not vendor files but rather your app files. You can put them under `src/Lib/`. Just ensure to use proper namespace for the classes and add proper `use` statement wherever you need to use your class.

For e.g. if your lib class is `src/Lib/FooBar.php` then it should have classname `App\Lib` and the "use" statement would be `use App\Lib\FooBar`.

Comment: 1) Is there a folder name convention for "src/Lib" in cakephp 3 ? Or is "src/Lib/Util" better ? 2) Should I add `use` statement in every class that I want to use `Foobar.php`, or is it possible to declare in one place and use it ? 3) What about Template folder's view files ? Can I add `use` statement in view files ?

Comment: 1) No, you can use any folder/namespace you want.
2) Yes, you need a `use` statement in each file you want to use. That's how namespacing works.
3) Yes you can have `use` statements in view files too.

Comment: @ADmad Is there any way we can load the FooBar class in bootstrap to load it all over the application?